# My Anet A8's filament isn't extruding properly

Tags: filament, pla, ultimaker-cura, anet-a8

So after a *lot* of work I finally got my Anet A8 printing but then disaster struck. It has stopped working again but with a new problem. The first few strokes of printing are fine but then it goes really stringy and the lines are very very thin so the result is a very stringy mess with holes and gaps everywhere. I am also using PLA from RS and my G-code and some images are below:

[image: Stringy print]

G-code: https://www.mediafire.com/file/p4odlic1372q78z/xyzCalibration_cube.gcode

Answer (score 1):

The most likely problem is that you have a jammed nozzle. To fix this heat the hot end up to about 140°C then insert some PLA filament push it through and then pull it out forcefully. That should solve your problem.

Comment: wait 240 degress or 140?

Comment: @VosemMedia 140

Comment: @VosemMedia First heat up to about 220 &deg;C, insert filament, let it cool a bit and pull it out, see [this answer](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/a/6092/5740). Filament heating up to 140 &deg;C will not lead to melting the old filament to bond with the newly inserted!